# Android annotation to call a specific function

Tags: android, annotations

When an instance of my class is made, it should always be closed, when the work is done.

```
public class MyClass {
    // I'm searching for an annotation like this:
    @RememberToCall(function="#close()")
    public MyClass() {
    }

    /**
     * Always call this function when you are done with your work.
     */
    public void close() {
        // Do some tear down stuff
    }
}
```

Similar to the [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) when executing an SQL query you are reminded to call the `close()` function on the cursor object that is returned. I want to do the same with my class, is there an annotation for that?